# Why is selenium not applying "click" to a popup?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I know the xpath of this popup tabs element is correct, however when I do `filters_language_dropdown.click()` and then `.send_keys(Keys.Enter`. It doesn't do anything.

However the same popup ([press 'filters' button on this page to view](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all)) works with the xpath of the initial button press element instead (see code + images below) so with `filters_button.send_keys...`. Whats going on?

[image] [image]

```
        # Initialize the browser and navigate to the page
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all")
        # (In working order): Look for keyword, make it clickable, clear existing data in box, enter new info, keep page open for 10 seconds
        search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search by keyword or advertiser']")))
        search_box.click()
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys("" "" + Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)

        # Activating the filters (English, active ads, date from (last 2 days) to today)
        filters_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")))
        filters_button.click()
        filters_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)

        filters_language_dropdown = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='js_knd']//div[@class='x6s0dn4 x78zum5 x13fuv20 xu3j5b3 x1q0q8m5 x26u7qi x178xt8z xm81vs4 xso031l xy80clv xb9moi8 xfth1om x21b0me xmls85d xhk9q7s x1otrzb0 x1i1ezom x1o6z2jb x1gzqxud x108nfp6 xm7lytj x1ykpatu xlu9dua x1w2lkzu']")))
        filters_language_dropdown.click()
        filters_language_dropdown.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Don't judge the behaviour from UI. Add the `HTML` source for the element you want to click.

Comment: @Akzy do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: It's in your question.

Comment: That doesn't help me understand what you meant but ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `xpath` to click on the `filter` and then click on `all languages` and then click on `English` if you want to change other language you need to pass let say 'French',you need to change instead of `English`.

**Code:**

```
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&q=%22%20%22&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_exact_phrase&media_type=all")

search=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Search by keyword or advertiser']")))
search.click()
search.clear()
search.send_keys("" "" + Keys.ENTER)

WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Filters']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='All languages']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='English']"))).click()
time.sleep(10) # to check the operation
```

Browser snapshot:

[image]